# Change Css inside the codebehind(C#)

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, namespaces

So I tried to change the value of the z-index of a div inside c#.

I tried it like that:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.attributecollection.cssstyle(v=vs.110).aspx

So now I can use the div inside of the c# with runat="server" but the CssStyle doesnt work.

```
div1.CssStyle.Add("z-index", "-1");
```

It can't find it but i'm using `using System.Web.UI;`

What do I need to use CssStyle?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `<div runat="server">/div>` tag, not the builtin `panel`.

You have 3 possibilities:

**First**

```
div1.Style.Add("z-index", "-1");
```

**Second**

```
div1.Attributes.Add("z-index", "-1");
```

**Third**

Change the div tag into `<asp:Panel runat="server"></asp:Panel>`, then you can use the property `CssStyle`.